# Why can't servicestack deserialize this JSON to C#?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, servicestack

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON representation to a strongly typed object.  I am able to serialize it from c# -> json, but not vice versa.

C#

```
public class Package 
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public List<string> Email {get;set;}
   public List<Items> Items {get;set;}
}

public class Items
{
   public string Uri {get;set;}
   public int Width {get;set;}
   public int Height {get;set;}
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "Id":"84fd8751-6107-41af-9473-65aae51e042a",
    "Email":[
    "j@t.com"
    ],
    "Items":"[
       {"Uri":"http://localhost/foo.jpg","Width":234,"Height":313},
       {"Uri":"http://localhost/bar.jpg","Width":234,"Height":174}]"
}
```

Code to deserialize

```
var instance = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Package>(jsonData);
```

The object `instance` is created, and there are 2 item objects in `instance.Items` but all of their properties are null.

TIA

Comment: this is me being brain dead - the JSON Items value was being set by JSON.stringify(items) in javascript - i was staring at the c# for so long...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have quotes around the Items value, thus parsing them as a string instead of an array/list. Remove them to win.

```
"Items":[
       {"Uri":"http://localhost/foo.jpg","Width":234,"Height":313},
       {"Uri":"http://localhost/bar.jpg","Width":234,"Height":174}]
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not valid JSON.  The quotation marks around the value for Items should not be there.

Comment: It is valid JSON, he is just deserializing it to a mismatched object.

Comment: @Brad It's actually not valid JSON.  Run it in JSONlint or similar. The string value would end after the second `"` so starting with `Uri...` the string is invalid.